# Hacking with Swift functions count is unavailable there is no universally good answer

Tags: swift, count

```
//functions swift
func countLetters(in string: String) {
    print("The string \(string) has \(string.count) letters.") 
}

countLetters(in: "Hello")
```

[image]

I don't understand why it says count is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see documentation comment for discussion.

Comment: You need to update your Xcode or check the `string.characters.count`
 instead

Answer (score 3):

Probably your version of Swift is too old. The `count` property didn't come into existence until Swift 4. In that case, you can say `string.characters.count` instead.

Comment: I wanted to correct that `count` existed in `Swift 1` and was removed in `Swift 2`, but then again I remembered that in `Swift 1` it used to be `func`. But anyways, it has to do with problem of should `String` conform to `Collection`(like in 1st and 4th) or not(like in 2nd and 3rd).

Comment: @user28434 yes but if you look at it closely she is using `print` not `println` which means Swift2 or later

Comment: @LeoDabus, yeah, I got it's not definitely not Swift 1. There were no doubts about it.